# How to copy primeNG tree ByValue in typescript which have Circular Structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, boost-propertytree

What is the most efficient way to clone a **primeNG tree** object which have Circular Structure?
I've done things like

1. `obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));` 
   //but JSON.stringify() not working for Circular Structuure.
2. `var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);`
3. `let newObject = this.copyObj(oldObject); 
   copyObj(obj) {
   // This is done because we need a copy of list, without this code it will copy a ref which will update file badges on create screen without add button click
   return [obj[0]];
   }`
4. `let newObject = Object.assign({}, oldObject);`

But all this method **Copy Object** **ByReference** not **ByValue**